# Using Glass mapper Api getting $name token instead of actual value from sitecore

Tags: glass-mapper

While Using Glass mapper Api getting $name token(default value) instead of actual value from sitecore field.While using sitecore API it works fine.This happens few of the item all others item works fine (using same templates).

Thanks in advance!!

***Provided by Pushpendra:***

**Code**

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(EventGroup)), SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{BE983705-200C-4F7B-87BD-CBE9382C856C}")]
public class BaseGroup : ISitecoreBasedObject { 
   [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{8D5DB0AC-ABEA-4668-8B05-77DCA9D5AC50}")] 
   public virtual string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

**Cshtml**

```
@foreach (ItineraryGroup g in itin.Groups) { 
   <h4>@g.GroupInfo.Name</h4> 
}
```

Comment: it was a great question not sure why it was off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Without more explation or code examples my answer would be that you are using a mix of master and web database.

If you are getting a item from the database and using SitecoreContext directly (which could then be web), then you could have a field mismatch.

Example of mismatch from the below link:

```
var db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var context = new SitecoreContext();
// the ID of Needed item
var g = new Guid("{F21C04FE-8826-41AB-9F3C-F7BDF5B35C76}");
// just to test if it's possible to fetch item using db.GetItem
var i = db.GetItem(new ID(g), Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);
// Grab item
var t = context.GetItem<Article>(g);
```

Correct usage:

```
var db = Factory.GetDatabase("web");
var context = new SitecoreContext();
// the ID of Needed item
var g = new Guid("{F21C04FE-8826-41AB-9F3C-F7BDF5B35C76}");
// just to test if it's possible to fetch item using db.GetItem
var i = db.GetItem(new ID(g), Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);
// Grab item
var t = context.GetItem<Article>(g);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521113/sitecore-glass-mapper-getitemtypenameguid-always-return-null

Comment: the answer doesn't even relate to the question.